Are factor models playing a chasing game?
Might be an obvious question (and taking inspiration from Digesting Anomalies: An Investment
Approach by Hou et al. (2014, RFS)), but are factor models playing a chasing game?
In the paper, the authors write the following paragraph:
In a highly influential article, Fama and French (1996) show that, except for
momentum, their 3-factor model, which consists of the market factor, a factor
based on market equity (small-minus-big, SMB), and a factor based on book-to-market equity (high-minus-low, HML), summarizes the cross section of
average stock returns as of the mid-1990s. Over the past 2 decades, however, it
has become clear that the Fama-French model fails to account for a wide array
of asset pricing anomalies.
Is it possible that as we progress through time, financial markets become more complex and therefore factor models (of the old) become insufficient to explain the cross-section of returns (and new asset pricing anomalies that appear in these returns as a result)?
Therefore, we can always expect a growing factor zoo to be necessary to meaningfully capture the cross-section of returns.

Andrew Y. Chen of the Fed has some research suggest that something is wrong with the asset pricing literature's current approach. In a long interview https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLbz3vKdZxM he explains his views. It is was not easy for me to follow all the arguments, and his papers are even more difficult, but they point to recent results raising doubts about earlier conclusions about factors. Including the surprising fact that the number of valid factors may be extremely large.

Thanks @nbbo2, I am halfway through Hou et al. and apparently many empirically motivated factors tend to be invalid, in the sense that these factors that do not have strong economic motivation need to have higher thresholds for significance, like t-stat of 3 instead of 2. I hope to hear more about this in your shared link. Can't wait to catch the interview you shared.
